# How many cases are there for this bifurcation?

Tags: bifurcation

Here is the bifurcation:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x(1-x)-h \frac{x}{1+x}$$

fixed points $$\ x = 0, -\sqrt {1-h}, + \sqrt {1-h} $$

How many cases are there?

My guess:

$$\ 0<h< 1$$
$$\ h > 1 $$
$$\ h < 0 $$

What are the cases?

Comment: Bob Dylan is studying math?

Comment: Yes. Help me out.

Comment: It is : (-inf, 1)

Comment: the cases are h = 1, h > 1, h<1?

Comment: My professor says not to ignore it. All solution will be <----<----<-----

Comment: Do notice there is a hole when h = 1 and x = -1? What do I do?

Comment: Now I am busy. I will come back to help you. BTW, I like Bob Dylan's songs.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,h)=x(1-x)-h\frac x{1+x}$. At $x=0$, 
$$ f_x(0,h)=1-h, f_{xx}(0,h)=2(h-1), f_{xxx}(0,h)=-6h.$$
If $f_x(0,h)\neq0$ or $h\neq1$, near $x=0$, the equation can be written as
$$ x'=(1-h)x+O(x^2) $$
which is equivalent to the linear equation
$$ x'=(1-h)x. $$
Thus if $h>1$, $0$ is stable and if $h<1$, $0$ is unstable.

If $f_x(0,h)=0$ or $h=1$, then $f_{xx}(0,1)=0,f_{xxx}(0,1)=-6\neq 0$. Near $x=0$, the equation can be written as
$$ x'=-6x^3+O(x^4) $$
which is equivalent to 
$$x'=-6x^3.$$
Thus $0$ is stable.

Now assume $0<h<1$. At $x=\sqrt{1-h}$, 
$$ f_x(\sqrt{1-h},h)=\frac{2(h-1)}{1+\sqrt{1-h}}<0.$$
Thus $x=\sqrt{1-h}$ is stable.
Now assume $0<h<1$. At $x=-\sqrt{1-h}$, 
$$ f_x(-\sqrt{1-h},h)=\frac{2(h-1)}{1-\sqrt{1-h}}<0.$$
Thus $x=-\sqrt{1-h}$ is stable.

For $x=-1$, let $u=x+1$ and then the equation becomes
$$ u'=\frac{(1-u)^3}{u}=\frac{1-3u}{u}+O(u).$$
Near $u=0$, this equation is equivalent to
$$u'=\frac{(1-u)^3}{u}=\frac{1-3u}{u}.$$
Thus $u=0$ is unstable or $x=-1$ is unstable.

Comment: The cases are h>1, h<1, and h =1? if you help me, I will make more songs.

Comment: @BobDylan, they are in the answer.